# How to make flex-end and flex-start for .logo and div?

Tags: image, flexbox, nav

I am trying to move #nav-bar elements to the right but it's not working. I want to put .logo to the left using flex-start but I don't think that's working. I think it's on the left by default.

I am new to css and html.

I tried making it into a flex box and using flex-end. I dont want to use inline or blocking. From what I understand, making display to flex and using flex-end will put the item to the right in a set row flex-direction  .

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
}
body{
  background-color:#b6eaf1;
  font-family:Cambria, sans-serif;
  
}

header{
  display:flex;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
  border:5px solid blue;
     }

.logo img{
width:17vw;
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start;
align-items:center;

}

img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#nav-bar{
    display:flex;
   }

#nav-bar ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:100%;
  gap:4vw;
  letter-spacing:2.5px;
 }

#nav-bar li{
  list-style:none;

}

#nav-bar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: blue;

}
```

```
         
                <header id="header">
                    
                   <div class="logo"> 
                       <img id="img-header" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.zjBOOZwVgo-4VI476pnY1QHaFk%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=55595a40798b691f4deffe4af60285dc33326fe0932e67b4acb29ea273dcffaa&ipo=images" alt="pikachu face logo">
                       </div>
                    
                     <nav id="nav-bar">
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#About_us">About us</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="Services">Services</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#Contact_us">Contact us</a></li>
                          </ul>
                     </nav>   
                     </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening is that the navbar is not getting the complete width to align the nav-bar elements to the right. Well if you give the `width:100%` and add the  `justify-content: right` to your `#nav-bar` it should fix the alignment. Please refer the complete code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #b6eaf1;
  font-family: Cambria, sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.logo img {
  width: 17vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

#nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img id="img-header" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.zjBOOZwVgo-4VI476pnY1QHaFk%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=55595a40798b691f4deffe4af60285dc33326fe0932e67b4acb29ea273dcffaa&ipo=images" alt="pikachu face logo"
    />
  </div>

  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#About_us">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="Services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#Contact_us">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```